# Assumptions about Announcer and other related badges

Tags: support, badges, publicity-badges

A question I shared a link to received 30 **views** in three days. However, I did not receive the Announcer badge. I assume the reason is one of the following:

- The 30 views were not from different IPs
- Views are not equivalent to visits
- Not every visit resulted from the link I shared

Are any of these reasons correct?

This makes me wonder what the criteria are for deciding what is a view/visit and what is not. For example, is there a time frame during which multiple visits from the same IP are considered the same visit and counted as one?

Answer (score 1):

1. 30 views probably means that your link wasn't used 25 times, as the OP and you didn't use your link...
2. Only visits from outside the StackExchange network counts toward the Publicity badges.
3. View equals to visit.

Comment: _Only visits from outside... count_ hmm well recently I've got an _Announcer_ for a link to SO answer I added to another answer ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4573833/839601))

Comment: @gnat. Maybe that linked was shared outside SE..., You won't get a badge otherwise.